# simplifying a function in swift

Tags: swift, function, dictionary, simplify

Newbie alert.

I would like to use this same code, on multiple pages of photos (to help my son recognize people). So instead of reinserting the name of each person, I created the appearingInPhoto (dictionary), so I can utilize just .a .b .c, instead of having to go an rename each line of code.

Is there a way to simplify the code further. So I can just have a code that check, if Button pressed (check the sender.currentTitle is equal to any of the dictionary values if yes, run this code:

```
print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.a)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.a
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.a
```

This is the full function now.

```
  var appearingInPhoto = (a:"omar", b:"john", c:"thomas")

  @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var soundName: String? = nil
    if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.a {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.a)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.a
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.a
    }else if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.b {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.b)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.b
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.b
    }else if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.c {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.c)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.c
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.c
    }
    if let soundName = soundName {
        playSoundFile(soundName)
    }
  }
```

THANK YOU in advance.

Comment: This should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Instead of checking `sender.currentTitle` why not (1) make things an array of tuple type `(String,String)` then (2) set the `tag` property of each `UIButton` with the index of the array element and then (3) use that in your function? It would eliminate the entire `if else` in your function.

Comment: `appearingInPhoto` is a tuple, not a `Dictionary`. And I don't exactly understand, what're you trying to achieve with this tuple?

Comment: Is the `appearingInPhoto` static in the app or will it's contents be changed? (and yes it does appear to be a `tuple` not a `dictionary`)

Comment: Sorry. You’re correct. I originally had it as a dictionary “Omar”, “John”, “Thomas”. And using .0 .1 .2 to call it. But I switched to tuple so I can give them more meaningful names. What I’m looking to do. Is instead of having a long if else statement with the 4 line of code for each person, is having a main function which runs all the names in the tuple/dictionary. I hope this clarifies it more. I can post a video to show you what I mean.

Comment: @mikeT Why not just an array or a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `Array` or a `Set`, along with `contains(_:)`:

```
let photoSubjects: Set = ["omar", "john", "thomas")

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let title = sender.currentTitle

    guard photoSubjects.contains(title) else { return }

    print("pressed \(title)")
    label.text = title
    let soundName = title
    playSoundFile(soundName)
}
```